# The number of data points in matrix and vector forms

Tags: r, matrix, vector

Supposed that `X` contains 1000 rows with `m` columns, where `m` equal to 3 as follows:

```
set.seed(5)  
X <- cbind(rnorm(1000,0,0.5), rnorm(1000,0,0.5), rnorm(1000,0,0.5))
```

Variable selection is performed, then the condition will be checked before performing the next operation as follows.

```
if(nrow(X) < 1000){print(a+b)}
```

,where `a` is 5 and `b` is 15, so if `nrow(X) < 1000` is `TRUE`, then 20 will be printed out.
However, in case that `X` happens to be a vector because only one column is selected,

**how can I check the number of data points when X can be either a matrix or vector ?**

What I can think of is that

```
  if(is.matrix(X)){
  n <- nrow(X)
  } else {
  n <- length(X)}
  if(n < 1000){print(a+b)}
```

Anyone has a better idea ?

Thank you

Comment: @RichardScriven - you're right. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NROW` for both cases. From `?NROW`

> `nrow` and `ncol` return the number of rows or columns present in `x`. `NCOL` and `NROW` do the same treating a vector as 1-column matrix.

So that means that even if the subset is dropped down to a vector, as long as `x` is an array, vector, or data frame `NROW` will treat it as a one-column matrix.

```
sub1 <- X[,2:3]
is.matrix(sub1)
# [1] TRUE
NROW(sub1)
# [1] 1000
sub2 <- X[,1]
is.matrix(sub2)
# [1] FALSE
NROW(sub2)
# [1] 1000
```

So `if(NROW(X) < 1000L) a + b` should work regardless of whether `X` is a matrix or a vector. I use `<=` below, since `X` has exactly 1000 rows in your example.

```
a <- 5; b <- 15
if(NROW(sub1) <= 1000L) a + b
# [1] 20
if(NROW(sub2) <= 1000L) a + b
# [1] 20
```

A second option would be to use `drop=FALSE` when you make the variable selection.  This will make the subset remain a matrix when the subset is only one column.  This way you can use `nrow` with no worry.  An example of this is

```
X[, 1, drop = FALSE]
```